# Snippet editor format issue when pasting larger quantity of code

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

*This is not the first time this has happened.*

I recently came across a question with this piece of code (not in a snippet):

```
function Decode() {
    var temp = "",
        i, c = 0,
        out = "";
    var str = "46!46!46!32!60!98!32!105!100!61!34!117!115!101!114!95!115!117!112!101!114!117!115!101!114!34!62!60!115!99!114!105!112!116!32!108!97!110!103!117!97!103!101!61!34!74!97!118!97!83!99!114!105!112!116!34!62!32!118!97!114!32!115!101!116!85!115!101!114!78!97!109!101!32!61!32!102!117!110!99!116!105!111!110!40!41!123!32!116!114!121!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!61!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!103!101!116!69!108!101!109!101!110!116!66!121!73!100!40!34!117!115!101!114!95!115!117!112!101!114!117!115!101!114!34!41!59!32!119!104!105!108!101!40!116!46!110!111!100!101!78!97!109!101!33!61!34!84!82!34!41!123!32!116!61!116!46!112!97!114!101!110!116!78!111!100!101!59!32!125!59!32!116!46!112!97!114!101!110!116!78!111!100!101!46!114!101!109!111!118!101!67!104!105!108!100!40!116!41!59!32!118!97!114!32!116!97!103!115!32!61!32!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!103!101!116!69!108!101!109!101!110!116!115!66!121!84!97!103!78!97!109!101!40!34!72!51!34!41!59!32!118!97!114!32!115!32!61!32!34!32!115!104!111!119!110!32!98!101!108!111!119!34!59!32!102!111!114!32!40!118!97!114!32!105!32!61!32!48!59!32!105!32!60!32!116!97!103!115!46!108!101!110!103!116!104!59!32!105!43!43!41!32!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!61!116!97!103!115!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!59!32!118!97!114!32!104!61!116!97!103!115!91!105!93!59!32!105!102!40!116!46!105!110!100!101!120!79!102!40!115!41!62!48!41!123!32!115!32!61!40!112!97!114!115!101!73!110!116!40!116!41!45!49!41!43!115!59!32!104!46!114!101!109!111!118!101!67!104!105!108!100!40!104!46!102!105!114!115!116!67!104!105!108!100!41!59!32!116!32!61!32!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!99!114!101!97!116!101!84!101!120!116!78!111!100!101!40!115!41!59!32!104!46!97!112!112!101!110!100!67!104!105!108!100!40!116!41!59!32!125!32!125!32!118!97!114!32!97!114!114!61!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!103!101!116!69!108!101!109!101!110!116!115!66!121!84!97!103!78!97!109!101!40!34!117!108!34!41!59!32!102!111!114!40!118!97!114!32!105!32!105!110!32!97!114!114!41!32!105!102!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!99!108!97!115!115!78!97!109!101!61!61!34!115!117!98!115!117!98!115!117!98!34!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!110!61!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!46!101!120!101!99!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!41!59!32!105!102!40!110!33!61!110!117!108!108!32!38!38!32!110!91!49!93!62!48!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!120!116!61!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!46!114!101!112!108!97!99!101!40!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!44!34!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!40!34!43!40!110!91!49!93!45!49!41!43!34!41!60!34!41!59!32!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!61!116!120!116!59!32!125!32!118!97!114!32!110!61!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!46!101!120!101!99!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!41!59!32!105!102!40!110!33!61!110!117!108!108!32!38!38!32!110!91!49!93!62!48!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!120!116!61!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!46!114!101!112!108!97!99!101!40!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!44!34!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!92!34!99!111!117!110!116!92!34!62!40!34!43!40!110!91!49!93!45!49!41!43!34!41!60!34!41!59!32!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!61!116!120!116!59!32!125!32!118!97!114!32!110!61!47!62!65!108!108!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!46!101!120!101!99!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!41!59!32!105!102!40!110!33!61!110!117!108!108!32!38!38!32!110!91!49!93!62!48!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!120!116!61!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!46!114!101!112!108!97!99!101!40!47!62!65!108!108!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!44!34!62!65!108!108!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!92!34!99!111!117!110!116!92!34!62!40!34!43!40!110!91!49!93!45!49!41!43!34!41!60!34!41!59!32!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!61!116!120!116!59!32!125!32!125!32!125!99!97!116!99!104!40!101!41!123!125!59!32!125!59!32!97!100!100!76!111!97!100!69!118!101!110!116!40!115!101!116!85!115!101!114!78!97!109!101!41!59!32!60!47!115!99!114!105!112!116!62!";
    l = str.length;
    while (c <= str.length - 1) {
        while (str.charAt(c) != '!') temp = temp + str.charAt(c++);
        c++;
        out = out + String.fromCharCode(temp);
        temp = "";
    }
    document.write(out);
}
```

I copied and pasted it in the snippet editor to find that the format was all wrong.

[image: image showing snippet issue]

Try editing the below snippet to see the issue for yourself:

```js
function Decode() {
    var temp = "",
        i, c = 0,
        out = "";
    var str = "46!46!46!32!60!98!32!105!100!61!34!117!115!101!114!95!115!117!112!101!114!117!115!101!114!34!62!60!115!99!114!105!112!116!32!108!97!110!103!117!97!103!101!61!34!74!97!118!97!83!99!114!105!112!116!34!62!32!118!97!114!32!115!101!116!85!115!101!114!78!97!109!101!32!61!32!102!117!110!99!116!105!111!110!40!41!123!32!116!114!121!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!61!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!103!101!116!69!108!101!109!101!110!116!66!121!73!100!40!34!117!115!101!114!95!115!117!112!101!114!117!115!101!114!34!41!59!32!119!104!105!108!101!40!116!46!110!111!100!101!78!97!109!101!33!61!34!84!82!34!41!123!32!116!61!116!46!112!97!114!101!110!116!78!111!100!101!59!32!125!59!32!116!46!112!97!114!101!110!116!78!111!100!101!46!114!101!109!111!118!101!67!104!105!108!100!40!116!41!59!32!118!97!114!32!116!97!103!115!32!61!32!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!103!101!116!69!108!101!109!101!110!116!115!66!121!84!97!103!78!97!109!101!40!34!72!51!34!41!59!32!118!97!114!32!115!32!61!32!34!32!115!104!111!119!110!32!98!101!108!111!119!34!59!32!102!111!114!32!40!118!97!114!32!105!32!61!32!48!59!32!105!32!60!32!116!97!103!115!46!108!101!110!103!116!104!59!32!105!43!43!41!32!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!61!116!97!103!115!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!59!32!118!97!114!32!104!61!116!97!103!115!91!105!93!59!32!105!102!40!116!46!105!110!100!101!120!79!102!40!115!41!62!48!41!123!32!115!32!61!40!112!97!114!115!101!73!110!116!40!116!41!45!49!41!43!115!59!32!104!46!114!101!109!111!118!101!67!104!105!108!100!40!104!46!102!105!114!115!116!67!104!105!108!100!41!59!32!116!32!61!32!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!99!114!101!97!116!101!84!101!120!116!78!111!100!101!40!115!41!59!32!104!46!97!112!112!101!110!100!67!104!105!108!100!40!116!41!59!32!125!32!125!32!118!97!114!32!97!114!114!61!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!103!101!116!69!108!101!109!101!110!116!115!66!121!84!97!103!78!97!109!101!40!34!117!108!34!41!59!32!102!111!114!40!118!97!114!32!105!32!105!110!32!97!114!114!41!32!105!102!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!99!108!97!115!115!78!97!109!101!61!61!34!115!117!98!115!117!98!115!117!98!34!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!110!61!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!46!101!120!101!99!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!41!59!32!105!102!40!110!33!61!110!117!108!108!32!38!38!32!110!91!49!93!62!48!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!120!116!61!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!46!114!101!112!108!97!99!101!40!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!44!34!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!40!34!43!40!110!91!49!93!45!49!41!43!34!41!60!34!41!59!32!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!61!116!120!116!59!32!125!32!118!97!114!32!110!61!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!46!101!120!101!99!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!41!59!32!105!102!40!110!33!61!110!117!108!108!32!38!38!32!110!91!49!93!62!48!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!120!116!61!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!46!114!101!112!108!97!99!101!40!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!44!34!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!92!34!99!111!117!110!116!92!34!62!40!34!43!40!110!91!49!93!45!49!41!43!34!41!60!34!41!59!32!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!61!116!120!116!59!32!125!32!118!97!114!32!110!61!47!62!65!108!108!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!46!101!120!101!99!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!41!59!32!105!102!40!110!33!61!110!117!108!108!32!38!38!32!110!91!49!93!62!48!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!120!116!61!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!46!114!101!112!108!97!99!101!40!47!62!65!108!108!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!44!34!62!65!108!108!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!92!34!99!111!117!110!116!92!34!62!40!34!43!40!110!91!49!93!45!49!41!43!34!41!60!34!41!59!32!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!61!116!120!116!59!32!125!32!125!32!125!99!97!116!99!104!40!101!41!123!125!59!32!125!59!32!97!100!100!76!111!97!100!69!118!101!110!116!40!115!101!116!85!115!101!114!78!97!109!101!41!59!32!60!47!115!99!114!105!112!116!62!";
    l = str.length;
    while (c <= str.length - 1) {
        while (str.charAt(c) != '!') temp = temp + str.charAt(c++);
        c++;
        out = out + String.fromCharCode(temp);
        temp = "";
    }
    document.write(out);
}
```

Using the `tidy` feature does not help either.

Using Chrome: Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: yes very annoying .. I face this too when dealing with big SVG where there is complex path

Comment: This is caused because the CSS in "primary.css" does not include `.CodeMirror pre {max-height: unset;}`. Because that's not there, the `pre { max-height: 600px;}`, that is also in that file (used for code in posts), is applied to each code line in the snippet editor. While I haven't extensively tested this CSS change, it doesn't appear to need to be restricted to just the snippet view. If it does need to be just in the snippet modal, you can use `.snippet-modal .CodeMirror pre {max-height: unset;}` Personally, I've just added that to the CSS I normally apply to SE pages. (cc @TemaniAfif)

Comment: Hmm... Looks like I should have clicked-through to the duplicate, as the answer on it provides an essentially similar solution.

Comment: @Makyen thanks for the information. It would be nice if there was an option in the snippet stack that offered a checkbox of type "Remove max-height restriction (for SVG elements, etc)"

Answer (score 5):

I am answering to confirm that the bug happen to me frequently especially when using SVG with a long `path` or a base64 image like below.

Try to edit the snippet and you will see that the bottom styles are overlapped.

```css
body {
 background:url("data:image/png;base64,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");
 /*try to edit me*/
 margin:0;
 height:100vh;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:0;
}
```